# Is is normal to have lxd process when running gitlab in a docker container?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ce, lxd

I run a self hosted gitlab-ce:15.2.2-ce.0 inside a Docker container on my linux server, but I notice that the memory usage is very high. All is caused by this user called lxd. I thought lxd is another kind of container, not related to Docker at all. So my questions are:

1. Is lxd used by gitlab ce?
2. Is it normal for gitlab ce to use this much memory to run?
   My server have 8GB of ram.
   [image]

Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GitLab runs most likely in your docker container under some user, which happens to have the same ID as the `lxd` user on your system, outside of the container. The processes that are running inside the container – `bundle`, `gitaly`, etc. are matched by `top` to the user with the ID that is defined in `/etc/passwd`, so there is nothing to worry about.

You can check this by executing `cat /etc/passwd` on your host system and inside tho docker container and compare the results.

To show the processes that only belong to the container, use `docker top`, e.g. `docker top gitlab`, if the name of your GitLab docker container is `gitlab`.

---

Regarding memory usage, the official GitLab documentation explains how to make configuration changes if memory is tight and your team is small: https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/memory_constrained_envs.html